# Magento 2 : Form data not saving

Tags: magento2, controllers, forms, save

I have an XML form on the backend. It has the save button the code for which is this -

```
class SaveButton implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface {

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
) {
    $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
    $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function getButtonData()
{

    $productId = $this->request->getParam('id');

    return [
        'label' => __('Save'),
        'class' => 'save primary',
         'data_attribute' => [
             'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
             'form-role' => 'save',
         ],
        'onclick' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl( '{moduleName}/{controllerName}/save','product_id' => $productId ] ),
        'sort_order' => 90,
    ];
}
```

When I click on save, it just reloads the page and doesn't take the control to the save controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove **onclick** parameter from the array. So looks like:

```
return [
    'label' => __('Save'),
    'class' => 'save primary',
     'data_attribute' => [
         'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'save']],
         'form-role' => 'save',
     ],
    'sort_order' => 90,
];
```

Comment: Tried it. It doesn't work with that either. I need it to go to module/controllerName/save.php

Comment: Submit url, you need to assign using UI component. Check example https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml#L35

Comment: Will try that. Thanks! How can I pass a parameter to the controller?